# Dagger compiler warnings

Tags: java, android, dagger

I've added a custom runtime annotation for fields in my project. Dagger now prints a warning for these annotated fields with each compile. Can I suppress this warning?

> Dagger will ignore qualifier annotations on fields that are not annotated with @Inject: my.package.MyClass.mField

Here is a code example:

```
@Inject
User mUser;

@Retain
private boolean mVariable; // Dagger complains about this variable
```

How can I suppress this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `@Retain` look like? If it is itself annotated with `@QualifierAnnotation`, remove that.

Comment: That was the issue. In fact, it was a copy & past mistake. The warning is correct. Thanks for your help!